# Package Dependency Issue

Tags: 14.04, package-management

I am unable to install anything at the moment because of dependency issue.
When I try to run `apt-get -f install`, the following happens;

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libopenni-sensor-primesense0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libopenni-sensor-primesense0
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 306 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/300 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,354 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 228186 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libopenni-sensor-primesense0 (5.1.0.41-3+trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/openni/GlobalDefaults.ini', which is also in package libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0 5.1.0.41.1-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If need be I am willing to wipe the slate clean and start again but I hope it doesn't come to that. Would appreciate any advice here please

Comment: Try with the command: `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.deb`

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work, thanks for the advice though

Answer (score 2):

This is a packaging issue, and a bug has been filed [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openni-sensor-pointclouds/+bug/1323887). This means that you can (safely) have only one of the two packages installed at any given time.

To keep `libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0`, run `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libopenni-sensor-primesense0` and `sudo apt-get install libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0`.

To keep `libopenni-sensor-primesense0`, run `sudo dpkg --remove --force-all libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0` and `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/libopenni-sensor-primesense0_5.1.0.41-3+trusty1_amd64.de‌​b`.

If there are any other packages that depend on these two packages, you'll need to remove those.

Comment: Hi mate, I am afraid that both attempts were unsuccessful. When I tried sudo dpkg -i <location> I got a message saying this was not a valid package.

Comment: In that case, try `sudo apt-get install libopenni-sensor-primesense0`.

Answer (score 0):

Saiarcot895, your advice was correct I did need to remove the packages and start again.
The only difference in how this was resolved was that when I  use:
sudo dpkg --remove --force-all 
for some reason the packages remain as "to be installed" when I run:
sudo apt-get update.

To get around this I just had to remove the package by using:
sudo apt-get remove libopenni-sensor-primesense0

This command removed the package from the "to be installed" list and finally resolved my issue. Thanks a lot for the help guys, very much appreciated.